# Cannot update sklearn on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am on a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook and I need to use version 0.22 or above to train and pickle my model. However, I cannot update the version of sklearn.

### Updating via pip

```py
!pip3 install sklearn --upgrade
```

Output:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already up-to-date: sklearn in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scikit-learn in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn) (0.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.17.0 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.4.1)
```

```py
import sklearn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

# The scikit-learn version is 0.20.3. <---- still 0.20
```

---

### Updating via Conda

```
!conda update scikit-learn -y
```

or

```
!conda update -n base scikit-learn -y
```

Output:

```
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.12
  latest version: 4.8.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

```py
import sklearn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

# The scikit-learn version is 0.20.3. <---- still 0.20
```

I have also run `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` or `conda update all` but still getting the same version.

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it seems the following should work:

```
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade sklearn
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, unfortunately it says `No module named pip3`

Comment: if you're running it from the jupyter notebook, you should be able to do `!python -m pip install -U sklearn`.

`python` will resolve to whatever that environment sees.

Comment: I was running jupyter notebook from sagemath. Was able to upgrade scipy using @mkostelac method.

Answer (score -2):

```
pip install sklearn --upgrade
```

or

```
pip install sklearn -U
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any space between `--` and `upgrade`, as in `--upgrade`